# When should I use a nested table and when a reference?

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

How should I decide whether to use a nested table or a reference?

For example:

We have an **airline** and a **flights** table:

```
CREATE TABLE airline OF airline_ty(
token VARCHAR2(8),
description VARCHAR2(20)
)

CREATE TABLE flights OF flights_ty(
flightNumber NUMBER(10)
securityLevel VARCHAR2(10)
)
```

Should I know make a reference in **airline** (`flights REF flights_ty`) or go for a nested table?

Comment: Most people would advise that in the real world, you'd never create a table based on a type or create a nested table in your data model.  They'd suggest that your data model should be purely relational.  Objects and collections are very useful in PL/SQL when you're working with data but not ideal for persisting data.  Are you asking about general industry best practices?  Or trying to understand where you should use one or the other in a class that is teaching you about those options?

Comment: I really try to understand the difference between this two options.

Comment: @user2993655 a nested table in oracle is a table within a table (a column of table A is another table B) which is as ugly and unrelational as it gets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the requirements for usage of the data. In your example with airlines and flights a flight should have a foreign key to its airline. The main table is flights and airlines is a codebook.

An example case where a nested table would be a good choice:
A customer in a core banking application has several phone numbers, email addresses etc. You need to hold this data for a customer, but you do not evaluate it (all customers with this email etc.), you just display it together with other customer detail. You cannot have an extra table for each one to many property, because you have much more interesting data, like accounts, loans, credit cards, account statements, behavior score cards etc.

You have always take into account, what will be the redundancy, reuse, importance, property vs. entity, aggregation vs. composition...